# I can only zoom to the center not to where i point

Tags: navigation

I am really new to blender and i want to zoom and rotate around an object not the cursor at the center.

Comment: zoom and orbit are 2 different things, to orbit around the selected object, open the Preferences and Navigation > Orbit Around Selection

Comment: or select the object and use "." (dot) of the numpad

Comment: Welcome to BSE @alenka , in Blender go to Edit > Preferences > Navigation, check Zoom to mouse position

Comment: Are you using Blender 2.9?

Comment: Make sure you didn't enable "Lock to cursor" in the viewport > N panel > View tab > View > Lock rollout, in that case zooming and orbiting will happen around the point where 3d cursor is

Answer (score 4):

In Blender 2.9, go to Edit > Preferences > Navigation, then check "Zoom to mouse position" for the zoom, and check "Orbit Around Selection" for orbiting.